# Unable to get RecyclerView ItemView position when scroll?

Tags: android

I am using  Chat RecyclerView in my chat app in which I have text, image and video 3 type ItemView. I update specific item using :

```
Recylerview.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int pos)
```

successfully, but when I scroll RecyclerView, change position of item view. So what solution for that? Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so you want to get view holder for given position or position for some view holder?

Comment: yes when i scroll recylerview update that item of specific position, i have also position but when i scroll position become changes

Comment: i have no idea what you mean...

Comment: you see whatsapp application when you send images the progressbar on image gone succesfully , i have also same thing but when i scroll the given position view not update that my issue bro

Answer (score 1):

In onBindViewHolder() function of your adapter you can use the below code to get  the position

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("position", holder.getAdapterPosition());
}
```